# Asymptotes: Why to find oblique asymptotes, do you equate the two leading coeffficients to 0.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

[image: proof]

I am looking at a technique to find asymptotes for a polynomial. I follow the steps, apart from where I have highlighted, surely an-1 can be any number and substituting u=0 into the equation gives an=0?

Comment: Why not give us an actual polynomial to try it on.  One where your "surely" differs from he quoted text.

Comment: @GEdgar Ok, well it only works if you equate the two leading terms, not just the leading term, but from the proof given I don't see why an-1 has to equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a formal procedure, but it works.

You have a rational function $f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$.

The equation of asymptote is $y=mx+c$

Then $$m=\lim_{x\to \infty}f’(x)$$
and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-mx=c$$